# gifted charts manejo de datos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

estoy ocupando react native para un proyecto de U, y estamos implementando graficas, la libreria se llama gifted charts,el problema viene a que esta no me lee los datos, estos deben ser pasado en este formato:

[{"label": "lunes", "value": 5}, {"label": "martes", "value": 5}]

formato el cual estoy pasandole, mi codigo se ve asi:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://api-taller4-fswo.onrender.com/api/ventas-por-dia")
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        // Crear directamente lineData utilizando response.data
        const lineData = data.map((registro) => ({
          label: registro.diasemana,
          value: parseInt(registro.cantidadventas, 10),
        }));
  
        // Asignar lineData a tus estados
        // Establecer lineData en el estado
        setLineData(lineData);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error al obtener datos de ventas:", error);
      });
  }, []);


return (
    <View style={styles_grafico_init.container}>
      <View style={styles_grafico_init.leftCharts}>
        <View style={styles_grafico_init.chartContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={RedirectToGrafico}>
          <Text style={styles_grafico_init.titulos}>Ventas 1</Text>
          
          <LineChart  initialSpacing={5} width={120} height={250} data={lineData}  />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        
  );
```

sé que el return está mal escrito, hay muchas más gráficas debajo que están comentadas asi que puse el lugar del problema.

el caso es que estoy transformando los nombres de mis variables para que la libreria pueda leerlas, el console.log me devuelve los valores de la forma que coloque arriba, pero el LineChart, no los toma, me arroja "Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.", pero si lo mismo que me imprime mi console.log(lineData) lo coloco directo, si lo toma, entonces no sé que estoy haciendo mal, lei la documentación y solo hay ejemplos con datos directos, que estoy haciendo mal?